# Numero random con decimales? c++

Tags: c++, c++11, ogre

Necesito generar un `Ogre::Real` de forma random, pero dudo que alguien trabaje con `Ogre`, entonces con un `float` me alcanza.

Entre 0.01 y 3.0

Comment: Hola Strelok, qué es lo que has intentado? Por qué te ha fallado: errores, problemas?

Answer (score 2):

Para empezar, [`Ogre::Real`](https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre/api/1.10/namespace_ogre.html#aa3a7b6dfb905e6572d62f0dfa3d4274d) es un alias de `float`, según se puede ver en la documentación:

> `typedef float Ogre::Real`
>
> Software floating point type.
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > Not valid as a pointer to GPU buffers / parameters

Una vez aclarado esto, usa [`<random>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) de C++11. No se que [distribución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_de_probabilidad) necesitarás en el rango 0.01f a 3.0f, pero generalmente en videojuegos lo deseable suele ser una [distribución uniforme](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_uniforme_discreta), así pues necesitas usar [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution):

```
std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generador(device());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribucion(.01f, 3.f);

std::cout << "Numero entre 0.01 y 3.00 : " << distribucion(generador) << '\n';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo y luego te comento.